# Migrating Apache OFBiz data from one system to another (system have similar configurations)

Tags: ofbiz

I have setup an E-Commerce on apache-ofbiz-12.04.02 which is running on Windows 7. Now I want to do same setup on my Friend's system. So is it possible to export the data from this OFBiz to another OFBiz on different system?

Well, there is a export all option in OFBiz, but it gives all .xml files as output, and those files are not getting upload on different OfBiz setup. Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "export all" files and then copy the files to the new system, and import these files again using ofbiz screens.

The other option is to do the migration at DB level.
Shutdown OFBiz to make sure nothing is modifying the DB, dump the DB, and then import the SQL dump into the new DB. Then you can start OFBiz in the new system and it will use the data...
HTH

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer. Where are you storing your data? Easy way is replicating the database. We do it all the time.